# $\int_0^1\large\frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\large\frac{(-1)^n}{r+ns}$ for any $r,s > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

The following problem appeared on a graduate level real analysis exam.

Show that for any positive real numbers $r$ and $s$,

$$\int_0^1\cfrac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\cfrac{(-1)^n}{r+ns}$$

I had no idea how to begin. Perhaps some dominated convergence argument? Hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Start with the identity

$$
\frac1{1+x^s}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{ns}
$$

(which holds for $|x|<1$) and justify why you can interchange the order of integration and summation.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve it.

Comment: @tangentbundle Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{x^{r-1}}{1+x^s} = x^{r-1}\cdot\frac 1 {1 - (-x^s)} = x^{r-1} \cdot\left( 1 - x^s + x^{2s} - x^{3s} + \cdots \right)
$$
The series converges to the expression on the left since $0<x<1.$

$$
\int_0^1 x^{r-1} x^{ns} \, dx = \frac 1 {ns+r}
$$

$$
0 \le x^{r-1}\big(1 - x^s\big) \le x^{r-1} \big(1 - x^s + x^{2s}-\cdots + (-1)^n x^{ns}\big) \le x^{r-1}
$$

$$
\int_0^1 x^{r-1} \,dx < +\infty.
$$
The function being integrated in the last line above can serve as the dominating function to show that the dominated convergence theorem applies.